# Verifying mongo db unit mocked unit tests

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, unit-testing, mockito

I have created a mock test for testing inserting into a mongodb DB. I am wondering how I can verify my unit test. The method insert returns a void. So how can I verify? Also, some methods don't return void. How can I verify those as well?

```
@Repository
public class DataDao<T> implements {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOps;

    public DataDao(MongoOperations mongoOps) {
        this.mongoOps = mongoOps;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Class<T> t, List<T> t1) {
        this.mongoOps.insert(t1, t);
    }
}

public class DataDaoTest {

    @Mock
    private DataDao<Data> daoMock;

    public static List<Data> getData() {
        // returns a list here
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert() {
        List<Data> data = getData();
        daoMock.insert(Data.class, data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for hand-writing your own DAO instead of using a `MongoRepository`?

Comment: Thats a good thought.. Should have probably done that. But the issue remains the same. How do I unit test it? @chrylis

Comment: I use https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo in a SpringBootTest